# How do I move a buffer in spacemacs to a different window / frame

Tags: spacemacs

Is there any keybinding or function to move an open buffer to a different window or a different frame in spacemacs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems key bindings have been changed in Spacemacs since @Nathanael's answer.

To move a buffer to a diffferent window, you can use `SPC b [n]` (buffer-to-window-[n]), where n is the number of the window to move to.

If you want to move the *window* , rather than the buffer (which makes sense in the light of the comments given above):

`SPC w [H|J|K|L]`

to move the window left|down|up|right, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The final sentence is the actual answer to the question (and what I came here looking for), and I very nearly missed it. Might be worth moving it to the top or calling it out better. :)

Answer (score 4):

In spacemacs (vim mode) you can press `SPC b m <your-direction>` to move a buffer. `<your-direction>` can be:

- `h` left
- `j` down
- `k` up
- `l` right

In emacs mode, it should be `M-m b m <your-direction>`

If you want to switch to the 'other' frame, you can use `SPC b M` (or `M-m b M`).

(In general, Emacs places no restriction on the number of windows/frames a buffer is displayed in, so you can simply switch to the buffer in however many windows/frames you want.)

Comment: and is it possible to move the buffer to a different frame? (ideal would be something comparable to ace-window to select the target window and frame)

Comment: You can just switch to the buffer when you are in the other frame, not sure if there's a native spacemacs way to do this though.

Comment: Perhaps to clarify, what I am looking for: I have a buffer open in one window want to open it in a different window and frame while closing it in the current one, so that I have the buffer open only in the target window and frame after the move

Comment: Perhaps you need something like `SPC b M` which puts the current buffer in the 'other' frame, then `C-x 5 1` to remove all other frames?

Comment: `SPC b M` is what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still valid — could these commands have changed because when I try to use `SPC b m` (or look at commands available in buffer mode) it gives the option to kill buffers (specifically `spacemacs/kill-other-buffers`), and does not offer to move the current buffer. `SPC b M` seems to be unmapped to any specific command and is remapped to `SPC b m` which is as before `spacemacs/kill-other-buffers`. There is a `move buffer to window` command but it doesn't seem to be mapped to anything in particular. I don't see anything about frames.

Comment: It's entirely possible; spacemacs doesn't worry too much about backward compatibility (in my experience) when it comes to changing keyboard shortcuts to make better sense.